# VS 2019 right click custom right click action

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I want to add action on right-click on solution explorer.
like I have a folder
"ABC" right-click on it (solution explorer).
Give option -> create folder structure.
After selecting
will create folders under it like

```
"ABC"
----- "Models"
----- "Enums"
----- "Interfaces"
----- "Implementations"
```

Comment: Are you trying to write code/extension to do this or are trying to customize VisualStudio using available features?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/file-nesting-solution-explorer?view=vs-2019 is this something that could help?